# Remove leading whitespace from files, folders and their subfolders

Tags: files, directory, rename

I came up with this, but unfortunately it doesnt affect any files/folders in subfolders.

```
find . -exec rename "s/^\s+//" {} \;
```

Folder structure:

```
foo
|-- \ bar
`-- \ foo1
    |-- \ bar1
    `-- \ foo2
        `-- \ bar2
```

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with the regex, but just for performance's sake, why not only rename files that actually start with a space: `find . -name " *" -exec rename [regex]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Renaming needs to be done from bottom to top

The issue is that you need to rename the directories *from bottom to top*. Else the command will try to rename files & directories which are inside already moved (renamed) folders, and thus cannot find them anymore.

This is where `python`'s `os.walk()` can be used, in combination with `topdown=False`

In a small script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import shutil
import sys

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1], topdown=False):
    for f in files:
        if f.startswith(" "):
            shutil.move(root+"/"+f, root+"/"+f.strip())
    for dr in dirs:
        if dr.startswith(" "):
            shutil.move(root+"/"+dr, root+"/"+dr.strip())
```

#### To use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `no_space.py`
- Run it by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/no_space.py /path/to/directory/to/rename
  ```

Comment: Thank you this worked like a charm. One hickup was with files that were in fact named with a whitespace, but I fixed them by hand. 
Over 600k files have been searched and renamed in just a few minutes!

Comment: @Sascha do you mean whitespace *inside* the name? Haha, I deliberately avoided that, because I understood it would have to stay :) It can be edited to do anything with the name(s).

Comment: Whitespaces inside the filename are not touched with your solution, which is exactly what I needed. But if a file is named `" "` (without the quotes). The script fails of course. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

As noted in other answers, the main issue is that `^` anchors the start of the *path*, rather than the start of the filename. There are several ways to work around that with `find` and `rename`: probably the safest would be to use `-execdir` in place of `-exec` so that all the path components reduce to `./`, and then replace the pattern `\./\s+`

Also, if you are renaming directories **possibly including ancestors of other files/directories that are to be renamed**, then you should do a depth-first traversal.

Putting it together,

```
find . -depth -name ' *' -execdir rename -vn -- 's#\./\s+##' {} +
```

or (functionally equivalent, but a bit easier to see what's happening) using a zero-length "lookbehind" for the path separator

```
$ find . -depth -name ' *' -execdir rename -vn -- 's#(?<=\./)\s+##' {} +
./ bar2 renamed as ./bar2
./ foo2 renamed as ./foo2
./ bar1 renamed as ./bar1
./ foo1 renamed as ./foo1
./ bar renamed as ./bar
```

[NOTE: remove the `-n` once you are sure it does what you want]

Comment: Using this expression gives me:

Comment: sorry, this is the output:
    Using expression: sub { use feature ':5.10'; s#(?<=./)\s+## }
    ' bar' unchanged
    ' bar1' unchanged
    ' bar2' unchanged
    ' foo2' unchanged

Comment: Sorry - I don't recognize that error message. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: My friend, on whose machine I'm ssh'd in right now told me this is in fact OSX 10.6.8 with 'BSD' rename. Should have checked the man beforehand, sorry. This explains the error message. Your solution is perfectly fine in Linux

Comment: @Sascha I kind of suspected as much - on *some* systems, the Ubuntu version of `rename` (which is actually a perl script) is available under the name `prename` - not sure if that extends to OSX though

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the output format of find, that includes the full path. So for bar2 you will have

```
./ foo1/ foo2 /bar2
```

that rename will not understand correctly.

A solution is to use a script to do each folder recursively like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# if argument given consider it is the directory to parse
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    cd "$1"
fi
# rename all files in current folder
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%f\0'  | xargs -0r -n 1 rename -nono 's/^\s+//'
# No, repeat for all subfolders with current script (we are in the subfolder)
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name '.' -print0 | xargs -0r -n 1 "$(readlink -f $0)"
```